# is there any way to get the date type columns in parse.com with custom date formatted, while requesting from angularjs $http get like order, limit?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2015-09-29T14:09:15.063Z",
      "objectId": "d12345zzcU",
      "updatedAt": "2015-09-29T14:09:15.063Z",
      "regDate": "2015-09-29T14:09:15.063Z",
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2014-08-23T07:00:00.000Z",
      "objectId": "312345Ozzy",
      "updatedAt": "2014-08-23T07:00:00.000Z",
      "regDate": "2014-08-23T07:00:00.000Z",
      "value": "ABD"
    }
  ]
}
```

is there any way to get the date type columns in parse.com with custom date formatted, while requesting from angularjs $http get like order, limit?

In the above result, i need to get result of "value" field in format like below, which is date type in parse db.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2015-09-29T14:09:15.063Z",
      "objectId": "d12345zzcU",
      "updatedAt": "2015-09-29T14:09:15.063Z",
      "regDate": "29/09/2015",
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2014-08-23T07:00:00.000Z",
      "objectId": "312345Ozzy",
      "updatedAt": "2014-08-23T07:00:00.000Z",
      "regDate": "23/08/2014",
      "value": "ABD"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? angular has built in date filter for formatting. Format you show is not a valid ISO format

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is any option, like getting the formatted date values in the response from the parse.com. Like sorting, limit option. So i can reduce the formatting in my angularjs codes - @charlietfl

Comment: Can always modify the data sent when you receive it. Is this through REST API or javascript SDK? Still not clear what specific problems you have using it as is

Comment: I am using API call, like https://api.parse.com/1/classes/statusHandler?order=-value, with headers for Rest Api key and applicaion id - @charlietfl